# django, получение value из html кнопки

Tags: python, django, html5

Через какую команду можно получить value из html кнопки в коде python?

На странице сайта идет отрисовка большого количества объектов из БД, у каждого объекта есть по 2 кнопки ("Зарегистрировать" "Отказ"), id этих объектов я записываю в value кнопки. Как проверить name кнопки я понял, но вот как проверить value я не знаю.

```
<div class="modal-footer flex-column border-top-0">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 mx-0 mb-2" name="Зарегистрировать" value="{{ el.id }}">Зарегистрировать</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-light w-100 mx-0" data-bs-dismiss="modal" name="Отказ" value="{{ el.id }}">Отказ</button>
</div>
```

Наверняка есть более удобный способ получить id объекта в коде python, через нажатие html кнопки буду благодарен, если опишите как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть подробное обсуждение этого вопроса: [How can I access the form submit button value in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607091/how-can-i-access-the-form-submit-button-value-in-django)

Но если интересует более правильный подход, тогда я бы поступил следующим образом:

1. Сделать hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value={{ el.id }}>`
2. Иметь 2 submit button с `name="success/decline"`
3. Во views проверять:

```
if 'success' in request.POST:
    // event for success
elif 'decline' in request.POST:
    // event for decline
```

Comment: А как получить id? У меня именно с этим проблемы, мне нужно оно, для переноса одного элемента таблицы в другую таблицу.

Comment: `id` это атрибут HTML элемента. При сериализации он не отправляется. На бэк прилетает только  словарь `name` и `value`

Comment: Я неправильно написал, я записываю `id` в `value` и не знаю как получить  этот параметр.

Я использовал ваш код: `<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value={{ el.id }}>` но он тоже  ничего не получил. Изменив его на: `<input type="hidden" name="{{ el.id }}" value="eef">` и `if` ( `if u in request.POST:` ) стал выдавать `true`, но как вы понимаете, это не запрос к `value`, а запрос к `name`.

В целом мне и так пойдет, но это выглядит как костыль, если честно.

Comment: Все верно, при запросе `if u in request.POST:` вы проверяет наличие ключа `u` в вашем `request.POST`. Если этот ключ есть - вы можете получить value используя `v = request.POST.get(u)`